# Cannot open .txt file in external hard drive when using Notepad++

Tags: notepad-plus-plus

As mentioned in the title, I have an issue when trying to open a text file located in my external hard drive using Notepad++.

- I can open the file using the default text editor that comes with Ubuntu
- I can open a text file on my computer (not external hard drive) using Notepad++

Below is the error message.

[image]

Comment: `Z:` looks like a *Windows* location. Are you using WSL on Windows? 

Comment: Probably the OP is using a snap version of Notepad++ under Wine64.

Comment: My guess is that since it is showing `media` in the location that it is another drive in the system that the snap cannot read to because it is outside of the `home` drive location.  I was reading out there where people have switched to using `notepadqq` as it is the equivalent program but not bound by the sandbox of snap apps.

Comment: I would suggest **Geany** or **Atom** editor instead of **Notepad++** which is not natively supported in Linux.

Comment: Or [notepadqq from flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.notepadqq.Notepadqq).